# Redirect to the same view while changing one parameter

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an ajax call that sends a country label to my view function below:

**views**

```
...
posts = Post.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST': 
    country = request.POST.get('country')
    print('COUNTRY:', country) #successfully prints
    posts = Post.objects.filter(country=country)

context = {
    ...
    'posts': posts,
}

return render(request, 'boxes.html', context)
```

I successfully get the ajax data but what do I do after this in order to redirect to the same view with the new `posts` value?

Comment: This should work if you call the url with paramter in your browser. It won't work if you fetch it via Ajax. For that you'd have to return a list of objects (maybe in json?) and use js to render it on your website.

Comment: It's an ajax call. I tried to put the parameter in the url, but how am I supposed to populate the parameter (in the url) via ajax? e.g. here's the url `url(r'^(?P<page>\w+)/(?P<country>\w+)/$', country_filter, name='country_filter'),` is it possible to populate the `country` via ajax?

Comment: You don't populate the url via ajax. You can just use a link, or with javascript the `window.location` API. Ajax fetches data from a server, not websites for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax.You have to use `window.location.reload();` in `success` method of Ajax post call.

Comment: But that doesn't go through the view, and I need it to go through the view to change the `posts` value. otherwise it just reloads the exact same page

Answer (score 0):

As i read that you are using Ajax:
The function reload @Himanshu dua said is ok
And i should check the way you use URL and VIEW

```
# The function reload will work well if you change the DATA 
# and it will reload and return again the New value from data
```

---

Or you should try to replace the old with the new DATA you got from Server via ajax (just change the value with Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way.

On the HTML page, using Javascript, you should:

- (1) Send an AJAX call (GET/POST) to load the view function in the
  backend
- (5) Receive the output of the view function and do whatever you want with it.

On the Backend, using the view function, you should:

- (2) Receive the GET/POST Data from the frontend (HTML)
- (3) Do whatever you want with that.
- (4) Return the output of the function as JSON using HttpResponse

> Note the numbers next to each item. It happens according to that
>   sequence from 1 to 5.

Here is an example:

1. On the HTML Page (Javascript):

```
    var posts;
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("/test/", function(data, status){
            posts = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

2. On the Backend (Python):

```
    import json
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def test(request):
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            country = request.POST.get('country')
            posts = Post.objects.filter(country=country)
            return HttpResponse( json.dumps(posts) )
        else:
            return HttpResponse( "error" )
```

Comment: Where is that `test()` function? is that inside my main view function?

Comment: Yes. But you have to configure the routing. Are you using Flask or Django?

Comment: I'm using Django.

Comment: Then, you have to add the following line to your urls.py file inside the urlpatterns list:

`url(r'^test/$', views.test),`

Comment: And the test() function should go in the views.py

Answer (score 0):

In your example the view returns a rendered template: `boxes.html`. For this to work, you would have to either

- modify your view to use query parameters (eg `/my/url?country=nowhere`). This would then work with GET requests instead of posts, and you can easily call it via URL.
- or use a html form instead of AJAX requests. A form can easily POST to an endpoint and it will load whatever your webserver returns.

Ajax calls are designed to exchange *data* with a server, not really for downloading whole webpages. So if you wanted to use ajax, you could make your view return a json/xml/whatever list of objects and then use js inject them into your page:

```
function successCallback(data) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('myelement');
  elem.innerHTML = data; 
}
```